# Laravel 4.1 setting multiple environments for both web & terminal

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel-artisan

Okay, I get the multi-environments from the [Laravel Docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/configuration#environment-configuration).

Here's my setup:

- local environment
- staging server environment
- production server

The local environment has a different hostname from the production server obviously, however the staging server is a subdomain on the production server (so `dev.myapp.com` vs `myapp.com`). I also use `myapp.dev` as my virtual hostname locally.

I've set the following to switch the enviornments:

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(function(){

if(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],'.dev') !== false) || strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],'dev.') !== false) {
    return 'local';
}
return 'production';
```

});

This *almost* works. The problem is I have a separate database setup for my dev/staging environments so that we're not showing or manipulating live data on the staging environment. This falls down in terminal. When I run `php artisan env` (after a warning message about `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` not being set) it shows as production.

That means it won't run migrations on the correct database through terminal.

What's a better way to reference this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
php artisan --env=staging
```

is what you need, and add `isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])` to the detection code, otherwise cli will complain.

Comment: will give this a try and come back. may take me a few days though. thanks

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if you've tried this but I would use the hostname instead of the domain. In your staging server using your CLI type `hostname` and it will tell you the hostname of your server.

You can add this to bootstrap/start.php

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(array(

    'local' => array('homestead'), // Change this to your local machine hostname.
    'staging' => array('staging_hostame'), // staging server
    'production' => array('your-production-machine-name'),

));
```

Let me now if you need further help on this :)

Comment: thanks, but my hostname for stagging and for production are the same as they're on the same server.